# Error while passing a simple HTTP call in java

Tags: java, http

Hi I'm calling a service in another host through a simple HTTP call by passing some values like below.

```
http://sbdmn.sbdmnn.col.lk/Submit?UserId=USER1&PasswordPASS1&SessionID=123456789&PhoneNumber=+9412345678967&MessageText=AMessage
```

It provides an error from the other end when I call through the following class.
Same URL working fine with the browser.

There are multiple calls for this service instead of Submit and it is working fine for all others.
I'm unable to get the actual error / cause for this from the other end.

I tried 
URLEncoder, with Proxy / without Proxy etc. So, what I have got to try more?

My code :

```
try{

URL                 url     = new URL("http://sbdmn.sbdmnn.col.lk/Submit?UserId=USER1&PasswordPASS1&SessionID=123456789&PhoneNumber=+9412345678967&MessageText=AMessage");

Proxy proxy_server = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("ProxyServerIP", 1234));
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("proxyUN","proxyPWD".toCharArray()));
    }
});

URLConnection       conn    = url.openConnection(proxy_server);

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);

OutputStreamWriter  wr      = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.flush();

BufferedReader      rd      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    responseStr = line;
        System.out.println(responseStr);
}

}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: It would help if you post the stack trace. Also, the character `+` in the phone number can be interpreted as a white-space and I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: I got some customized error gave from the service. The guy who on the service is not providing me the stack trace .:(